# In MongoDB can you group two indexes together from different collections?

Tags: database, mongodb

In this scenario I'm making a database for cocktails, I have a collection for cocktails which has a one to many relationship with ingredients.

I would like to add a quantity object to the ingredient per cocktail, so something like this...

Cocktail Schema

```
{
   cocktail_id: string,
   cocktail_name: string,
   ingredients: []<ingredient> ie... [{ ingredient: 'gin', quantity: 1 part }]
}
```

Ingredient Schema

```
{
   ingredient_id: string,
   ingredient_name: string,
}
```

How I would go about doing that?

Comment: You can do it the way you described it.

Comment: @D.SM well that's a little awkward, cheers though